# One can integrate every monotonic function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

I have a question related to the proof of "One can integrate every monotonic fucktion $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$." that I have as assignment. We are referring to Riemann integrals here.

The idea I came up with is the following:

A function is integrable in $[a,b]$ if

$$\int_a^{*b} f(x) dx = \int_{*a}^b f(x) dx$$

$*b$ marks an integral constructed with upper sums; $*a$ one constructed with lower sums.
My approach will be to make the difference between upper and lower-sum integral > $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon > 0$.

Now let $x$ be in $[a,b]$.
If a function is monotonic in $[a,b]$ then the function is bounded set by $\max f(x)$ and $\min f(x)$ which are equivalent to $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. That means that the difference between upper and lower sums can't be greater than $|f(b) - f(a)|$.

That is where I am stuck at the moment. With some Research I have found out that one solution would be to divide the Interval $[a,b]$ into small pieces called $\delta$ and say construct 
the following:

$$\delta\cdot|f(b) - f(a)|<\epsilon $$

They say (I guess): When $|f(b) - f(a)|<\epsilon$ then $\delta\cdot|f(b) - f(a)|<\epsilon$ if $\delta$ is chosen small enough. Thus you can make let $\delta$ Approach zero and not violate any rule. Therefore the difference between upper and lower sum becomes ~0 and every monotonic function is integrable.

I must say that I have Problems with this approach. I don't understand why delta is multiplied with the interval. I understand its purpose but I don't see a clear proof in that statement. That is why I've modified it so it may become clearer:

First of all I would not divide the  interval into small pieces the way stated above but rather define two step functions $\phi_{[x_{i-1},x_i]} := c_i$ and $\psi_{[x_{i-1},x_i]} := d_i$ where $x_i = a + i\frac{b-a}{n}$ with $i = 1,2,3\ldots,n$.

I would then not look at $|f(b) - f(a)|$ but rather at $|f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})|$ and thus define $c_i := \max f_{[x_{i-1}, x_i]}$ (upper sum) and $c_i := \min f_{[x_{i-1}, x_i]}$ (lower sum).

Now I may say that by approaching n to infinity every interval $|f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})|$ would shrink $<\epsilon$ no matter how small $\epsilon$ is. Therefore the difference between upper and lower sum becomes ~0 and every monotonic function is integrable.

But I have Problems with that solution as well. What if we have a function that makes a big bump at $x_b$ which is possible having just monotonic functions isn't it? Applying the Solutions above to that would make the upper and lower sum around that bump differ alot and thus make the function not integrable at least in that local area. And apart from that - is this really a proper proof for the Statement in the assignment? I have the strong feeling that it isn't.

Thank you very much for your help!

FunkyPeanut

Comment: See Yiorgos' answer for a good approach to solving the problem.  To address your concerns, note that the fact that the function is monotonic on a closed interval means it's bounded, and being monotonic, those "bumps" you described have to be small, even when all added together.  So you can't "always find" another big bump as you're subdividing, which seems to be your concern.

Comment: Thank you! That makes it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right track.

Note that, for your uniform partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ into $n$ subintervals
$$
U(f,P)-L(f,P)=\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \big(f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})\big)=\frac{b-a}{n}\big(f(b)-f(a)\big).
$$

Comment: Thank you! I think I will be able to solve the Problem with this Approach! :)